# displaying maven pom version in freemarker

Tags: struts2, freemarker, pom.xml

In jsp i can easily display version of the .pom by using ${version}.

When I try the same in freemarker template, logically, action getVersion method is called (struts2).

Is there a way to show maven version directly in freemarker template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done it is to add a property file like "applicationResources.properties" to the src/main/resources directory with a version property:

```
application.version=${version}
```

and then in the pom add:

```
<resources>
   <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>
</resources>
```

and then in the struts.xml add:

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="applicationResources" />
```

and then in my JSP:

```
<s:text name="application.version" />
```

For Freemarker, you should then be able to use:

```
<@s.text name="application.version" />
```